# Android ListView SimpleCursorAdapter TextView and ImageButton

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView backed by a SQLite db table which displays a song title (TextView) and a button (ImageButton) in the list item XML for each row. I setup an onClick() event for the button to take action on the song on the row they clicked on.

The ListView correctly displays all contents from the db table using a SimpleCursorAdapter.

Here's the question: when I click on the ImageButton it correctly calls the onClick event for the button with parameter (View view); how do I get to the Cursor row data for the row in which the button was clicked from the View passed into the event? I need the row _ID value in order to act on the correct song. I also have access to the dbAdapter in a Class field if I can get there from that object.

Notes: When I add an ImageButton to the Item List the onItemClickListener no longer fires if I click on the row containing the song or on the button.

And please, if there is a better design pattern to give the user the functionality of selecting a ListView item and performing an action on it, let me know. My intention is to eventually add 2-3 buttons per row for Delete, Info, Play, etc.

```
// Load ListView with previously downloaded files
dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

// Create Cursor holding db data
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchData();

// Map db columns to view ids
String[] columns = new String[]{
        DBContract.Songs.COLUMN_NAME_NAME,
        DBContract.Songs.COLUMN_NAME_LOADED_DATETIME
};

int[] to = new int[]{
        R.id.songName,
        R.id.songDateLoaded
};

// Create the dbAdapter
dbAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.songs, cursor, columns, to, 0);

// Assign the adapter to the ListView
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.songsListView);
listView.setAdapter(dbAdapter);

// Anonymous OnItemClickListener
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {...
```

Comment: You can use the `setTag()`/`getTag()` methods to attach the IDs to your `ImageButton`s.

Comment: Hi Mike, are you suggesting that I use setTag() in the adapter getView() method? But I have not overridden that method as I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter and therefore did not even instantiate an Adapter class. Perhaps I am missing your point. But I thought that the point was to use the SimpleCursorAdapter and have no need to implement the CursorAdapter object. And, to be sure, you are saying that there is no other way to get to this information on the onClick event and the View parameter???

Comment: You don't have to subclass it. You can use a [`SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html). And, yeah, there are other ways, but that's probably about as simple as they get

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am a relative newbie to Android, coming back to it after 5-6 years away. Might as well be an eternity. I am not sure how ViewBinder would work as you mention above. I just took a look at the documentation that you kindly provided the link to.
It also seems that I could just use an ImageView instead of an ImageButton and then I can use the onItemClick() event which contains the info I need in the event parameters. However, in this case, how do I know that the user click on one of the images (and which ImageView) as opposed to simply the song title? 
Either way works for me.

Comment: A `ViewBinder` gives you the ability to set a `Cursor`'s data on the given `View`s however you need; e.g., if the raw data in the `Cursor` isn't exactly what you want to display, you can process/modify/translate/etc. in the binder, instead of letting the `Adapter` set it blindly as is. In this case, if your `Adapter` is already good to go, then you don't need to use it for that purpose, really, but to attach some extra data on the `View`s. Returning false from `setViewValue()` will tell the `Adapter` to just do what it normally would. As for the `ImageView`, yeah, that'll let you use an...

Comment: ...`OnItemClickListener`, where you get the ID for free, but there's not really any available method to know which child `View` of the item layout was clicked; not without some additional modifications, anyway, as far as I can think of.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the tutorial. Very helpful in my current state. You have confirmed my intuitions about how this works. However, just one more request please. Can you give a code example of how I would set the TAG for the ImageButton to be the _ID for the current Cursor row please. It is not intuitive to me, and an example would be worth a thousand words as the saying goes. Thx

Comment: fyi - added my code sample above in original post for you to see

Comment: Cool. Good to have. And, yeah, I could throw something together, but it'll be a little bit before I can. However, before we go down that road, have you considered using a `RecyclerView` instead? `ListView`s and `GridView`s and all that are kinda deprecated (not technically, in the docs). I just mention it, because if you stick with this, you're eventually going to run into somebody (or multiple somebodies) who's all like _"OMG! Why aren't you using `RecyclerView`?!"_ I guess I feel obligated to give you the disclaimer.

Comment: I don't want to get 'dinged' for lots of comments, but the docs for RecyclerView say "If your app needs to display a scrolling list of elements based on large data sets (or data that frequently changes)..." - that wasn't the case here. Not a large data set or data that frequently changes for me. But I will investigate.

Comment: I threw together a test to make sure I thought everything through correctly, and I'm pretty satisfied with it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10q11-eajTfFjlXCx9hJrXfrMuIqKJeVT/view?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: Excellent Mike. Sorry I couldn't get to this until just now. I am unclear about one thing. "R.id.songItemView, // <-- Add this android:id to the root of songs.xml". What is this View type? Where do I add it exactly? I have a constraintlayout which holds the TextView and ImageButtons. Sorry for being dense about this.

Comment: No worries. It would go on the outermost – the "root" – element in the `songs` layout. It sounds like that's the `<ConstraintLayout>`, so you'd add `android:id="@+id/songItemView"` to that. You can use whatever name you want, btw. I just went with `songItemView`, as it seemed to be in line with your naming convention, and likely wasn't used yet. Also, I guessed that the variable name for your ID column is `DBContract.Songs.COLUMN_NAME_ID`, so you might need to change that, if it's not.

Comment: Thanks Mike! A couple things: being a relative newbie to both Android and StackOverflow, I keep getting prompted to 'avoid long comment conversations and to switch to a chat'; please initiate that on your end if you feel it is what we should do. Question #1: when you bind to a View, what property does it bind to? setText()? Also, after reading, it seems as if I don't need to bind to the ConstraintLayout at all. Instead just stick with my normal bindings, and on the ViewBinder() if it is the first View, assign ID to tags and return false; thus forcing the binder to do its default action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198252/discussion-between-mike-m-and-user2184214).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mike's persistent and patient assistance, I implemented the solution below.

The key is using a setViewBinder() on the SimpleCursorAdapter and then assigning the db row key to the Tag property of the ImageButton. Then, in XML, define an onClick() event and in that event, you now have access to the db row key from the view.getTag() method.

```
// Bind the Cursor record _ID to the ImageButton Tag property;
// So when it is called, we can delete the record with the Tag property value.
dbAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int i) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.songName) {
            final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Songs._ID));
            final ImageButton delete = ((View)view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.deleteSongButton);
            delete.setTag(id);
        }
        return false;
    }
});

public void DeleteSong(View view) {
    final long id = (long) view.getTag();
    dbHelper.RemoveSong(id);
    dbHelper.fetchSongsAndUpdateAdapter(dbAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Song removed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Thanks Mike!